# Loop wont run as expected

Tags: python

I am just learning python, and I am trying to make hangman, but I am having two problems. First, when you enter the same letter twice, it follows two of my conditions, and the prompt for both gets printed twice. For example:

```
> C:\Users\Me\PycharmProjects\Python\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Me/PycharmProjects/Python/Hangman.py
shark
There are 5 letters in this word.

You have 3 wrong guesses left.

Guess a letter. 
s
Good guess. That letter was in the word.
You have 3 wrong guesses left.

Guess a letter. 
s
*You already entered that letter.
Good guess. That letter was in the word.*
You have 3 wrong guesses left.

Guess a letter.
```

Another issue I am having is making the win condition. If the correct_guesses reaches zero, it should end the game, but it doesnt actually work, as it always ends the game after 4 correct inputs.

```py
import random

my_list = ["hangman", "dragon", "tiger", "octopus", "shark", "money", "school", "stadium", "biker", "whale", "sphinx"]
my_list2 = []
word = random.choice(my_list)


print(word) #Delete later
print("There are", len(word), "letters in this word.")


def start():
    guesses_left = 3
    correct_guesses = len(set(word))
    while guesses_left > -1:
        print("You have", str(guesses_left), "wrong guesses left.\n")
        guess = input("Guess a letter. \n").lower()
        if len(guess) != 1:
            print("Please enter a single letter.")
            continue
        if guess in my_list2:
            print("You already entered that letter.")
            continue
        if guess not in my_list2:
            my_list2.append(guess)
        if guess in word:
            print("Good guess. That letter was in the word.")
            correct_guesses -= 1
            continue
        if guess not in word:
            print("That letter isn't in the word.")
            guesses_left -= 1
            continue
        if correct_guesses == 0:
            print("Congratulations! You won the game.")
            break
    if guesses_left <= 1:
        print("Sorry, you lost. Play again.")


start()
print(my_list2) #Delete later
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you've edited the code signigicantly based on the other answer. Your last problem of it not stopping to say that you've won is because the code never reaches the win condition, as if the entered letter is correct or not, it will hit a `continue` before you test for `correct_guesses == 0`. You can fix that by simply moving the test to the start of the loop instead of the end.

```
def start():
    guesses_left = 3
    correct_guesses = len(set(word))
    while guesses_left > -1:
        if correct_guesses == 0:                        #
            print("Congratulations! You won the game.") # Move it here
            break                                       #
        print("You have", str(guesses_left), "wrong guesses left.\n")
        guess = input("Guess a letter. \n").lower()
        if len(guess) != 1:
            print("Please enter a single letter.")
            continue
        if guess in my_list2:
            print("You already entered that letter.")
            continue
        if guess not in my_list2:
            my_list2.append(guess)
        if guess in word:
            print("Good guess. That letter was in the word.")
            correct_guesses -= 1
            continue
        if guess not in word:
            print("That letter isn't in the word.")
            guesses_left -= 1
            continue
    if guesses_left <= 1:
        print("Sorry, you lost. Play again.")
```

Answer (score 1):

The second time 's' is entered it still matches:

```
if guess in word:
            print("Good guess. That letter was in the word.")
            correct_guesses -= 1
```

How about:

```
if guess in word and guess not in my_list2:
            print("Good guess. That letter was in the word.")
            correct_guesses -= 1
```

Or you could change the overall structure to:

```
if 
  ...
elif
  ... 
else
 ...
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you meant in the last part, where I change it to if, elif, else? If I am understanding correctly you want the first condition to be if, the last condition to be else, and every condition inbetween to be elif? I tried it and it doesnt seem to be working properly. It wont give me "this is in the word" or "this isnt in the word" or even the "this is too many letters, enter just one."

Comment: It should. It might be helpful to look for first error first which is "this is in the word". Are all your indentations right up to the 'if' that prints "this is the in the word"? Maybe edit the question or create a new one with your new code?

Comment: Make sure your only using spaces.

Comment: I wasnt able to figure it out with elif, but I added a continue after each condition and now it works. I still cant figure out how to get the win condition to work properly. Even though the number need to win should be the number of distinct letters in the word, it always 'wins' after 4 correct inputs.

Comment: After 4 guesses, loop ends and it drops to bottom. correct_guesses must be set wrong initially. Print out correct_guesses right after you set it. Is it right?

Comment: I figured out why correct_guesses was four. I used 'word' instead of just word, so now it correctly gets the number of correct guesses. Now I just cant get it to stop the loop and say "you won" when correct_guesses = 0

Comment: I just saw this too. Good job figuring it out. If your done, mark this solution correct.